# Validity checks are not working in my function

Tags: r

So I was starting to make my code

```
myplot2=function(d,a){
  if(!(is.data.frame(d)))
    stop("Error:Is not dataframe")
  
  if(a!= 1 || a!= 2){
    stop("Error:Has to be one or two")
  }
  
  
}
```

My problem is that this happens when i actually plug in 1 or into the data.

```
> myplot2(patients,1)
Error in myplot2(patients, 1) : Error:Has to be one or two
> myplot2(patients,2)
Error in myplot2(patients, 2) : Error:Has to be one or two
```

Why is my validity check  failing to work properly?

Comment: I think you mean `a!= 1 && a!= 2` (you need an "and" not an "or"). You can also do `!a %in% 1:2`

Comment: @MrFlick I guess I did not think this through logically. Sigh. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing your own validity checks, another option is to make use of one of the available R packages. For example, using `assertthat`:

```r
library(assertthat)
myplot2 <- function(d, a) {
    assert_that(is.data.frame(d))
    assert_that(length(a) == 1 & !a %in% 1:2)        
    "all good"    
}

# Examples
myplot2(NULL, 4)
# Error: d is not a data frame 
myplot2(mtcars, 1)
#  Error: length(a) == 1 & !a %in% 1:2 is not TRUE 
myplot2(mtcars, 0)
# [1] "all good"
```